# Woocommerce reporting queries issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble displaying all completed orders. I have this site that uses [WPLMS](http://vibethemes.com/envato/wplms/skins/default/) theme.

I need to show the custom reporting but I am unable to understand the database. I would like to have this info:

Name of Course purchased
Name of person who purchased it.
Voucher code used to buy it
Date of purchase
Amount paid

This query is working fine on one website that uses Academy theme but on WPLMS it returns null

```
select (select `pm4`.`meta_value` from `wp_postmeta` `pm4` where 
((`p`.`ID` = `pm4`.`post_id`) and (`pm4`.`meta_key` = '_customer_user'))) 
AS `student_id`,(select `pm3`.`meta_value` from `wp_postmeta` `pm3` 
where ((`p`.`ID` = `pm3`.`post_id`) and (`pm3`.`meta_key` = '_order_total'))) 
AS `order_total_sum`,(select `wpoi1`.`order_item_name` from
 `wp_woocommerce_order_items` `wpoi1` where ((`wpoi1`.`order_id` = `p`.`ID`) 
and (`wpoi1`.`order_item_type` = 'coupon')) limit 1) 
AS `coupon_used`,(select `wpoi2`.`order_item_name` from 
`wp_woocommerce_order_items` `wpoi2` where ((`wpoi2`.`order_id` = `p`.`ID`) 
and (`wpoi2`.`order_item_type` = 'line_item')) limit 1) AS 
`product_name`,`p`.`post_date` AS `order_date`,`p`.`ID` AS `ID` from 
(`wp_posts` `p` join `wp_term_relationships` `wptr`) where 
((`p`.`post_type` = 'shop_order') and (`wptr`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`) 
and `wptr`.`term_taxonomy_id` in (select `wp_terms`.`term_id` from 
`wp_terms` where (`wp_terms`.`slug` = 'completed')));
```

This returns no rows but if I remove the below code from the end

AND (`wptr`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`) 
        and `wptr`.`term_taxonomy_id` in (select `wp_terms`.`term_id` from 
        `wp_terms` where (`wp_terms`.`slug` = 'completed'))

I receive all the rows with so many empty columns in it. This is working perfectly on one website. Let me know what is the issue. Also in my database there no slug named "completed"

Thanks